# How to minimize the RAM requirements for copying data from (large) partitioned table to another partitioned table?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-partitioning

For two big tables, table1 and table2 with thousands of partitions and 150 million rows in table1, mysql/mariadb performs this query inefficiently.

```
insert into table2 select * from table1
```

In fact, using 8192 partitions on both tables, RAM was exhausted before the query ended. I had to terminate it when it had allocated 6.1 GB of RAM, since this particular box had only 8 GB of RAM. How can this task be performed with a lower RAM footprint?

Answer (score 0):

By forcing mysql/mariadb to deal with data from one partition at a time, the task could be completed, using less than 500 MB RAM at any point.

The structure of the solution is like this:

```
insert into table2 select * from table1 partition (p<X>)
```

where X should be the full set of integers that correspond to the partitions, in my case from 0 to 8191. This can be implemented esing a stored procedure as this one:

```
drop procedure if exists my_partitioning_data_copy_procedure;

delimiter #
create procedure my_partitioning_data_copy_procedure()
begin

declare v_max int unsigned default 8191;
declare v_counter int unsigned default 0;

  start transaction;
  while v_counter < v_max do
    SET @expression = concat("insert into table2 select * from table1 partition (p", v_counter, ");");
    prepare myquery from @expression;
    execute myquery;
    set v_counter=v_counter+1;
  end while;
  commit;
end #

delimiter ;

call my_partitioning_data_copy_procedure();
```